# Is it better to prewrite the dashboard data or fetch and do the calculation on demand?

Tags: node.js, database, mongodb, performance, dashboard

So the thing is that i have some data in my Mongodb that i want to represent in a dashboard,
And its taking some time to fetch the selected documents from different collections and do the calculations needed to send the results back to the client.

So i had this idea to pre-write the required data in the required format in a dedicated collection and whenever the client asks for the dashboard i just fetch its data directly, so that i don t have to wait to fetching data across different collections and to do the calculations when he asks for it.

by the way these data are not getting updated frequently… lets say about 100 updates max per day.

Does this idea sound right or it has some drawbacks that i didn t think about?

Thank you in advance,

Answer (score 1):

That's caching, your idea sounds just right.